# How to install jPicker?

Tags: jquery

I downloaded jPicker - A jQuery Color Picker Plugin (http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/) and tried to install it on my website, but small picker icon doesn't show, I only have text field (I tried jPicker Binded version).

Here's my code:

```
<link href="/css/jPicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/jPicker-1.1.6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/jPicker-1.1.6.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="/js/jpicker-1.1.6.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jpicker-1.1.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">        
  $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
      $('#Binded').jPicker();
    });
</script>
<input id="Binded" type="text" value="e2ddcf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your scripts out of order.  jquery should always be first.